# ExtJS / Javascript - Date field is being converted improperly via GUI

Tags: javascript, date, extjs, store, extjs5

Looking for some assistance regarding how my date field is being presented via my GUI.

**Questions:**

1. I select the date field via a calendar - if I select 2016-02-07 and save it to the database, why is the GUI displaying the date in GMT (2016-02-06)
2. For the start_time and end_time fields, why does it save to my database prepended with "2008-01-01T"?

Some background information:

Database Type: PostgreSQL

ExtJS: 5.0.1

**Database is storing the values as:**

date = 2016-02-07

start_time = 2008-01-01T05:00:00

end_time = 2008-01-1T07:00:00

**GUI is displaying the values as:**

date = 2016-02-06 (it looks like it is converting the DB value to GMT)

start_time = 5:00 AM

end_time = 7:00 AM

**Store:**

```
Store.model.Base.defineModel(
'Ticket',
[{name: 'attributes_id', type: 'int'},
{name: 'number', type: 'string'},
{name: 'date', type: 'date'},
{name: 'start_time', type: 'date', dateWriteFormat: 'g:i A'},
{name: 'end_time', type: 'date', dateWriteFormat: 'g:i A'}
],
true
```

);

**View:**

```
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Details',
                layout: { type: 'hbox', align: 'stretch' },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    style: { paddingRight: '10px' },
                    items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    fieldLabel: 'Number',
                    id: 'Number',
                    name: 'number',
                    width: 250
                    },
                    {
                    xtype: 'datefield',
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date',
                    format: 'Y-m-d',
                    submitFormat: 'c',
                    id: 'Date',
                    name: 'date',
                    width: 250
                    },
            {
                    xtype: 'timefield',
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    fieldLabel: 'Start Time',
                    id: 'StartTime',
                    name: 'start_time',
                    minValue: '12:00 AM',
                    maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                    format: 'g:i A',
                    increment: 60,
                        width: 250
                    },
            {
                    xtype: 'timefield',
                    labelAlign: 'top',
                    fieldLabel: 'End Time',
                    id: 'EndTime',
                    name: 'end_time',
                    minValue: '12:00 AM',
                    maxValue: '11:00 PM',
                    format: 'g:i A',
                    increment: 60,
                        width: 250
                    }]
                },]
```

**Save:**

```
    _constructSaveStore: function(config) {
    var me = this;
    var store = config.store;

    this._tasks.push({fn: function() {
        if(store.getModifiedRecords().length > 0 ||
            store.getRemovedRecords().length > 0)
        {
            store.sync({callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                        me.setStatus(success);

                        if(!operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                            var message = "Failed to save changes on server.";

                            if(operation.hasException())
                                message = message + " " + operation.getError();

                            var app = CarrierDMZ.getApplication();
                            app.toast(message,'error');
                        }                           
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            me.setStatus(true);
        }
    }});
}
```

**Form Definition:**

```
            region: 'center',
            xtype: 'form',
            id: 'TicketForm',
            autoScroll: true,
            bodyPadding: 10,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The most important code is missing. Please show how you submit your data to the server. Do you use `store.sync`, `model.save` or `form.submit`? And how is your form defined?

Comment: I'm using a store.sync function - I've added it and the form definition into the code above.

Answer (score 2):

**Read/write date values from/to the server**

There is a multitude of options how to read/write date values from/to the server.

The problem is that the JSON standard does not have a special data type for dates. Dates can be transmitted as strings, ints, or objects in various formats, or even in (deliberate) violation of the JSON standard ("the Microsoft way").

A date itself is a complex object, being both an integer of seconds since a certain time, and a value that tells you which time zone you are in. Time Zones in itself are complex objects again, there are 104 of them known to the Windows operating system alone. [Now go figure what happens when different bodies try to build a standard](https://xkcd.com/927/) around that chaos.

When you use `form.submit()`, the form will stringify all date field values. AFAIK there is no option how to stringify them in a self-defined way; ExtJS will always produce a default string. It depends on the backend whether it can understand that default string, because as I already mentioned, there is no standard.

When you use `model.save()` or `store.sync()`, the approach is different. The form will hand over to the model a JavaScript date when you say `form.updateRecord()`; and if the model field is of `type:date`, it will store a javascript date. When stringifying the date for submission, the field makes use of the `dateWriteFormat` or `dateFormat` config, which is subsequently respected during both `save()` and `sync()`. During this conversion, ExtJS does handle time zones only in some cases, depending on the format.

When calling `store.load` or `model.load`, the same goes into the different direction. But instead of `dateWriteFormat`, the read method uses `dateReadFormat`. The conversion is completely reversible if you use the same values for both. But

- when reading "2016-01-01" using `dateFormat:'Y-m-d'`, the date is 2016-01-01 **00**:00:00 GMT+01:00 on my computer.
- when reading "2016-01-01" using `dateFormat:'c'`, the date is 2016-01-01 **01**:00:00 GMT+01:00 on my computer.

**If you mix both formats, which is what you do (using `g:i A` as dateWriteFormat and the default `c` as dateReadFormat), everything goes haywire.**

So the recommended way is to not use form load/submit, and to favor `dateFormat` over `dateWriteFormat` and `dateReadFormat`. If you always specify compatible formats (`Y-m-d H:i` or `c`, not both), and also do the conversion correctly on the server side, you will be safe. [Also note that sencha has hidden a very strong suggestion to that regard somewhere in the docs.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Date-cfg-dateFormat)

**Time Fields**

Time fields select a time, but JavaScript date values also need a date. So ExtJS invented the following initialization which you can override for certain time fields if you wish:

```
initDate: '1/1/2008',
initDateParts: [2008, 0, 1],
initDateFormat: 'j/n/Y',
```

Make sure that both initDate and initDateParts are in sync, or else hell may break lose. But most of the time, you would use `dateFormat:'H:i'` for the field in the model, skipping out the date completely. For the time field, the date is just a placeholder. When comparing time field values, make sure that the time fields have the same initDate (they usually do, unless you override them).

Comment: "*A date itself is a complex object,*", Not really, it is **only** a time since the epoch and bunch of inherited methods. The time zone offset is not a property of a Date instance, it's retrieved from the host system. Try this: create a date and call *getTimezoneOffset*. Now change the system timezone and call it again. What does trip people up is parsing strings or mixing time zones inadvertently (per your answer).

Comment: Is there anyway I can strip the 2008-01-01T fully from the timestamp? All I want to store is the time itself into the database.

Comment: When transmitting time for storage in MS SQL Server's `time` type, I use `dateFormat:'H:i:s'`. Please refer to your database's documentation for the required format. If the database stores the date at all, you are using the wrong database column type.

Comment: I've added dateFormat: 'H:i:s' to my timefields and the store field as well. When I try to submit the record my error check still says the form is trying to submit the value prepended with January 1st 2008:

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type time with time zone: "Tue Jan 01 2008 02:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"

Comment: @robg I think Alexander are referring in the context of Sencha framework because they are! one little change and you will be days trying to figure out.

Comment: @Jukebox: Then don't use `form.submit`, use `form.saveRecord` and then `model.save`. After `form.saveRecord`, the model should contain a javascript date, and `model.save` should use the model field's `dateFormat` for serialization. Don't let the form do any serialization at all.

Comment: @jamesjara—fair enough, but isn't that the framework's issue rather than ECMAScript's Date? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would configure all different components with the same format.

1. To store field:

   ```
   type: "date",
   dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:s"
   ```
2. To Editor component:

   ```
   xtype: "datefieldscheduler", 
   format: "Y-m-d H:i",
   ```
3. to Grid column:

   ```
   xtype: "datecolumn", // Ext.grid.column.Date
   format: "Y-m-d H:i:s",
   renderFormat: "Y-m-d H:i"
   ```
4. As the last resource overwrite date format,(you can see here format from database, for example)

   ```
   Ext.define('Admin.overrides.Date', {
     override :'Ext.form.field.Date',
     dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
     dateReadFormat:'Y-m-d H:i:s',
     dateWriteFormat : 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
   });
   ```

In this example we are using the same format internally, to display in different format use renderFormat.